# Am I using the right elasticsearch query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, bonsai-elasticsearch

Using the [elastsearch-rails](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails) gem, currently I have:

```
response = Employee.search(
      size: 20, 
      query: {
            multi_match: { 
                  "query" => search_terms,
                  "type" => "cross_fields",
                  "fields" => ["first_name^3", "last_name^3", "full_name^4", "email", "job_description^5", "job_title^5"]
            }
        }
    )
```

What I notice is that by doing the multi-match / cross_fields search, if I search for a term that appears only once in an Employee database column (e.g., "John" would only appear in first_name, not job_description or job_title), then I get no results back.  If a term, (say a job title like "lawyer" appears in more than 1 field such as job_description and job_title), I get results back.  Why is this?  This seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: elastic-search version?

Comment: using version 1.2.2, though I can easily upgrade to the latest if that would solve the problem

Comment: can you paste the mapping for the above fields